# In iTextSharp, how do I change background color of existing Rectangle, after having set background color of same rectangle with PdfContentByte?

Tags: itext

Below is code to initially set the rectangle(this code works). Thought I could use same code to set to another color, but that did not work.

```
AcroFields.FieldPosition f = form.GetFieldPositions(key)[0];
PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetUnderContent(f.page);
Rectangle rect = f.position.GetRectangle(f.position.Top, f.position.Bottom);
BaseColor yellowColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
rect.BackgroundColor = yellowColor;
pdfContentByte.Rectangle(rect);
```

Comment: Your code users `stamper.GetUnderContent` of the page in question. Thus, when adding a rectangle the second time, you add it underneath the existing one. Thus, the second rectangle is hidden by the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different things.

You want to change the *background color of the widget annotation* of a field, which is a legitimate requirement. Surprisingly, that's not what you do in your code. In your code you change the *content of a page* by using  `stamper.GetUnderContent(f.page);`

Annotations and page content are two completely separate things:

- Page content consists of (a) stream(s) of PDF syntax referred to in the `/Contents` entry of a page dictionary.
- Annotations are objects that are rendered on top of this content. Annotation dictionaries are referenced in the `/Annots` entry of a page dictionary.

You should change the background color of the widget annotations, not draw some rectangle in the page content. Changing the background of a field `key` in a form `form` is done like this:

```
form.SetFieldProperty(key, "bgcolor", BaseColor.YELLOW, null);
```

If you want to change that color to yet another color, just use the same line, but with a different color parameter.